# sqlplus out of process memory when trying to allocate X amount of memory

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

We are using sqlplus to offload data from oracle using sqlplus on a large table with 500+ columns and around 15 million records per day.
The query fails as oracle is not able to allocate the required memory for the result set. 
Fine tuning oracle DB server to increase memory allocation  is ruled out since it is used across teams and is critical.
This is a simple select with a filter on a column.
What options do I have to make it work?

1) to break my query down into multiple chunks and run it in nightly batch mode.
If so , how can a select query be broken down 
2) Are there any optimization techniques I can use while using sqlplus for a select query on a large table?
3) Any java/ojdbc based solution which can break a select into chunks and reduce the load on db server?

Any pointers are highly appreciated.

Here is the errror message thrown:
ORA-04030: out of process memory when trying to allocate 169040 bytes (pga heap,kgh stack)
ORA-04030: out of process memory when trying to allocate 16328 bytes (koh-kghu sessi,pl/sql vc2)

Comment: What is the exact error message and error number?

Comment: "offload".  Is this for archival purposes?  Would something like data pump work?

Comment: It is a nightly offload to a target DB and not for archival.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ORA-4030` indicates the process needs more memory(UGA in SGA/PGA depending upon the server architecture) to execute job.

This could be caused by shortage of RAM(Dedicated server mode environment), a small PGA size, or may be operating system setting to restrict allocation of enough RAM.

This MOS Note describes how to diagnose and resolve `ORA-04030` error.

Diagnosing and Resolving ORA-4030 Errors (Doc ID 233869.1)

Comment: I don't think DBAs would be ready to meddle with defaults set by oracle. Do we know if the default values set are not good enough for a sqlplus client application fetching 15 million records? Also I don't see any particular details in the article on any benchmarking done.

Comment: It's not the problem related to SQLPLUS. When you connect to the database using SQLPLUS the Oracle will create a server process to serve your request. The server process is unable to get the memory which is allocated from PGA(is controlled by memory parameters).

Comment: I understand that. That is why I said DBA may not be ready to change the defaults set at oracle server unless I go with some hard facts and figures about how much memeory is a process triggered at oracle DB resulting from query execution from a sqplplus client is going to take etc.

Answer (score 0):

Your option 1 seems in your control. Breaking down the query will require knowledge of the query/data. Either a column in the data might work; i.e.

```
query1: select ... where col1 <= <value>
query2: select ... where col1 > <value>
```

... or ... you might have to build more code around the problem.

Thought: does the query involving sorting/grouping? Can you live without it? Those operations take up more memory.